# Animation in status bar like in Mailbox app

Tags: android, android-animation

Any idea how to implement animation in status bar like in Mailbox app?

[image: Mailbox screen]

[Link to the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mailboxapp)

What I'm curious the most is the fade in & fade out animation and that the list can be scrolled during it.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to find out any solution for this, i am also stuck in doing it

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in android 4.4.4 and 5.0.

```
 WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        int statusBarHeight = (int) Math.ceil(25 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("I am on top of status bar");
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                statusBarHeight,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;

        windowManager.addView(textView, params);
```